# Specify minitoc for each chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc, etoc

To specify the toc depth of each chapter I can do

```
\chapter{Title}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}
...
\chapter{Title}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
...
```

How can I do this for the minitoc? Setting the minitocdepth counter does not seem to work.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Answer from 2013**

(slightly rearranged for readability, and with a more complete code sample starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`)

With the [etoc](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoc) package, you generate `minitoc`'s with the command `\localtableofcontents`. You can modify the `tocdepth` counter before this command.

It is better (except if intentional) to avoid  using `addtocontents` to inscribe some `tocdepth` changing instruction to the `.toc` file: indeed this will impact all the tables of contents inside the document.

Here is the code, to illustrate how one can modify the `tocdepth` counter in the document at the location where the TOCs are inserted.

Sorry if I am off-topic as I couldn't tell if `minitoc` was a specific reference to the [minitoc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minitoc) package.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoc}
\begin{document}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}% down to subsections in main TOC
\tableofcontents

% redefine the headings of the future TOCs to use \section* rather than \chapter*
\etocarticlestyle

\chapter{Vincere}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}% local TOC displays only sections
\localtableofcontents

\section {Section 1}
\subsection {1.a}
\subsection {1.b}

\section {Section 2}
\subsection {2.a}
\subsection {2.b}

\chapter{Vincere ancora}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}% local TOC again displays sections and subsections
\localtableofcontents

\section {Section 3}
\subsection {3.a}
\subsection {3.b}

\section {Section 4}
\subsection {4.a}
\subsection {4.b}

\end{document}
```

---

**Update in 2O15**

A few months after this answer was posted in 2013, `etoc` got enriched with two new commands `\etocsettocdepth` and `\etocsetnexttocdepth`.

Package `hyperref` takes into account the local value of the `tocdepth` counter in its decision of what goes to the bookmarks (but see its option `bookmarksdepth` as documented in its `README`). It is thus advisable to use `\etocsetnexttocdepth` whose effect extends only to the typesetting of the next `TOC` be it local (`\localtableofcontents`) or global.

The `\etocsettocdepth{<level>}` should be used once in the preamble or near the beginning of the document to set the `tocdepth` counter to a given value. The `<level>` may be numeric or a name.

The `\etocsetnexttocdepth{<level>}` is for temporarily setting the `tocdepth` counter to a value only for the time of typesetting a TOC. This way no impact on the global bookmarks occurs.

Here is thus how the code above can be written with `etoc` `1.07g [2013/10/13]` or later, in a way which avoids any disturbance of the global hyperref bookmarks:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}% for testing
\begin{document}

\etocsettocdepth{subsection}
% the main TOC goes down to subsections, and the bookmarks too.
\tableofcontents

% redefine the headings of the TOCs to use \section* rather than \chapter*
\etocarticlestyle

\chapter{Vincere}
\etocsetnexttocdepth{section}
% this local TOC goes down to sections, there is nil impact on bookmarks
\localtableofcontents

\section {Section 1}
\subsection {1.a}
\subsection {1.b}

\section {Section 2}
\subsection {2.a}
\subsection {2.b}

\chapter{Vincere ancora}
% this local TOC again displays down to subsections, like the main TOC
\localtableofcontents

\section {Section 3}
\subsection {3.a}
\subsection {3.b}

\section {Section 4}
\subsection {4.a}
\subsection {4.b}

\end{document}
```